# Trim a String without Builtins

Tags: code-golf, string, restricted-source

Given text, remove leading and trailing whitespace (spaces, tabs, and newlines).

Alternate title: Implement your own string trimming.

## Input

ASCII text (printable + spaces, tabs (`\t`), and newlines (`\n`)), in whatever format you would like. Carriage returns (`\r`) are outside of the scope of the input.

## Output

The same text in the same format, but with (only) trailing and leading spaces, tabs, and newlines removed.

*Note: If your language naturally outputs a trailing space/newline, please note that in your answer.

## Test Cases

This test case ensures that you can handle `\s` and the like. Please note whitespace in it.

Input

```
 \s test \t\n
```

Output

```
\s test \t\n
```

For the following test cases (but not the above), `\s` is space, `\t` is tab, `\n` is newline. `=>` splits input and output.

```
\s\t\n\s => (empty string)

\stest\s => test

\nt\n\st\t => t\n\st

_ => _

\s\s\n\s1\s+\s1\n => 1\s+\s1

||_\s => ||_
```

No builitins allowed that trim either specific characters or given characters. Builtins that remove arbitrary characters from the beginning/end of a string, or that remove given characters from any position in a string (by default) are allowed.

Comment: It's not exactly clear what you mean by *no built-ins*. Is regex allowed?

Comment: Maybe you mean that a trimming function removes a substring from both sides of a string?

Comment: @StephenS Yeah that's what I mean.

Comment: How about trimming by an integer amount (rather than "remove occurrence of this character"), dequeuing (removing the first item), popping (removing the last item), rotating, splitting?

Comment: Why would dequeue not be allowed? How is `s[1:]` trimming?

Comment: @Dennis OK, clarifying this for the last time, deleting all my comments.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as unclear because I do not feel that the questions of what is considered a builtin has been completely or reasonably addressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 bytes

```
>⁶TṬo\Tị
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@2/3qHFbyMOda/JjQh7u7v7//z8nZ1JiUiVXWWJeZk5OIpQHAA)

Comment: Baby, vanilla baby ;)

Comment: Character comparisons work?!

Comment: @JonathanAllan Why would they not? Integers and character have the same depth.

Comment: I just seem to recall them not working.

Comment: @JonathanAllan You probably recall trying to compare strings. *That* won't work since `>` vectorizes.

Answer (score 3):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 10 bytes

```
^\s+|\s+$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#@x8XU6xdA8QqXP//c5VwKZRwAgA)

Trailing newline is added automatically and is unavoidable.

Comment: Retina can do better. I'm really tempted to post it as a separate answer though.

Comment: @Neil go ahead.

Comment: Never mind, found a bug in my answer.

Comment: might be shorter to use matching with something like: `(\S.+?)\s+`

Answer (score 1):

## [Carrot](https://github.com/kritixilithos/Carrot/), 21 bytes

```
#^//\S([\s\S]*\S)?/gS
```

[Try it online!](http://kritixilithos.github.io/Carrot/)

#### Explanation

Carrot has several global variables, one for each type: string, float and array. The program starts in string-mode, where all the operators will affect the global string variable. And I call these variables the "stack".

```
#^                     Set the stack-string to the value of all of the input
/                      Get matches of this regex:
 /\S([\s\S]*\S)?/g
                       And set the stack-array to the array containing these matches
                       There will only ever be one or zero matches
S                      Convert to string-mode by joining the elements of the array
```

The `S` operator is supposed to take a string or number as an argument to join the array on, but apparently it is not needed in this case (I don't understand why).

Answer (score 1):

## JS (ES6), 27 bytes

```
i=>i.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"")
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>11</s> 8 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

-2 bytes thanks to Dennis (use direct character conversion, similar to his answer `O>32` -> `>⁶`
-1 byte thanks to Dennis (removing a redundant quick)

```
>⁶TṂr$Ṁị
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@2/3qHFbyMOdTUUqD3c2PNzd/f//f4WYYoWS1OIShZiSmDwuBQA)**

Steering clear of anything that could be considered "trimming".

#### How?

```
>⁶TṂr$Ṁị - Main link: list of characters (a.k.a. string)  e.g. "  t xt  "
 ⁶       - literal space character
>        - greater than (vectorises)                           [0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0]
  T      - truthy indexes                                      [    3,  5,6    ]
     $   - last two links as a monad
   Ṃ     -   minimum                                                3
    r    -   inclusive range                                   [[3],[3,4,5],[3,4,5,6]]
      Ṁ  - maximum                                             [3,4,5,6]
       ị - index into the input                                 "t xt"
```

Comment: `>⁶TṂr$Ṁị` works too.

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 40 Bytes

Regex Version

```
<?=preg_replace("#^\s+|\s+$#","",$argn);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/php#s7EvyCjgUkksSs@zVVKIKVGIyVMwVNBWMIzJU7Lmsrf7b2NvW1CUmh5flFqQk5icqqGkHBdTrF0DxCrKSjpKSjpgvZrW//8DAA)

### PHP, 77 Bytes

The Regex version was so boring so I would try it without a Regex

```
<?=substr($a=$argn,strspn($a,$c="\t\n "),-strspn(strrev($a),$c)?:strlen($a));
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/php#LYsxDoAgEAR7XnEhFF7EglZAPkKDhmhhCAH0@3gaq83s7BqXj8xEKHuyHHwDn0DBCMonrplbunG2XmttZRDBfjtJUHMilmKz3De6cJTTX1OUeJNF0uhm4jO@a0Td@wM)

Answer (score 0):

## C (gcc) & preprocessor, <s>152</s> 149 bytes

```
#define f(x)(x==32|x==9|x==10)
char*t(char*o){int i=strlen(o);for(;--i>0;){if(!f(o[i]))break;o[i]=0;};while(1){if(f(*o))o=o+1;else break;}return o;}
```

-3 bytes: Ironically, I forgot to remove my spaces.

A function that takes in a `char*` (pointer to the first character of the string (how C implements strings)), and returns a pointer to the first non-space character in the string, and also replaces all trailing spaces with null bytes, C's string terminator.

Ungolfed:

```
#define isspace(x) (x==32|x==9|x==10) 
// save bytes by not using this whole thing each time
// (32 is ' ', 9 is '\t', 10 is '\n')
char *trim(char *original) {
    int i=strlen(original);
    for(;--i>0;){                   // start at the end of the string, work backwards
        if(!isspace(original[i]))
            break;              // if the character not is a space character, stop working backwards
        original[i]=0;          // else: replace the character with a null byte, C's string terminator
    }
    while(1){
        if(isspace(original[0]))// shift the pointer until the first char is not a space
            original = original + 1;
        else break;
    }
    return original;            // return the modified pointer
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 44 bytes

```python
lambda s:re.sub(r'^\s*|\s*$','',s)
import re
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#LcZBCsIwEAXQdecUfyEklZIDFNx5AA8QhIlJIWBjmRkXgnePWbh48LZL7E/eU2boKiXoO3lx96jn73Byi3OLzlT34yUGKf0//SgdUpth8@NBLdcWpHD289wBRIUVNUSLjQhgJJ4ePFkhWq/DjSj8AA)

### Non-regex: 62 bytes

Takes input as list of characters. Outputs by reference.

```python
def f(s):exec'while s[%s].isspace():del s[%s]\n'*2%(0,0,-1,-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 9 bytes

```
e"^%s|%s$
```

[Try it online](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.4&code=ZSJeJXN8JXMk&input=IiAgIHRlc3QgCQoiCi1R) (`-Q` flag used for visualisation only)

Answer (score 0):

## C#, 60 bytes

```c#
s=>System.Text.RegularExpressions.Replace(s,"^\s+|\s+$","");
```

If I could use built-ins this is only 12 bytes:

```c#
s=>s.Trim();
```